# Android Studio: APK Build Failed

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently installed Android Studio(3.4.1) and wanted to install the sample Hello World app onto my phone, but every time I try to build the APK file I get the following error message:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues
> Task :app:generateDebugResources
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> 8 exceptions were raised by workers:
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1-5326820-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
8 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 5 up-to-date
```

I am totally new to Android Studio and would like some help to fix the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your project level build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
```

In gradle-wrapper.properties change the distributionUrl to

```
https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

Comment: You can accept the answer if it worked for you. Cheers